# Dependent variable - sometimes known exactly, sometimes just by inequality (>).. technique to use both?

Tags: time-series, predictive-models

let's say you have an anonymous auction of a certain kind of item. The winner will, well, win the item, and obviously know the price they bid for it.
An unsuccessful participant will only know that he didn't win, i.e. that the price they bid was not high enough.

Now let's say you want to model the price the item will auction for (dependent variable), based on a few inpur factors (say, number of auction participants, maybe their demographics etc. etc.).

The data set you can use for calibration contains one record per past auction, sometimes from a winner (with the exact price - so knowing this won the auction), and sometimes from an unsuccessful bidder (with the price they bid - so only knowing this price wasn't high enough, and the true price was > that value).

Now all modeling techniques I'm aware of assume a specifically known dependent variable, i.e. I could just use the records from the auction winners.
But clearly, the data from unsuccessful bidders contain some informational value as well - but only in the form of an inequality (auction price was higher than xyz).

Are there any statistical techniques that would allow me to incorporate both kinds of records?

I'd be interesting in any and all techniques/models that may allow to incorporate this, be it classic regression models, machine-learning based models or anything else that comes to mind.
All gooling so far has been quite unsuccessful, so even just a keyword to look for would be quite helpful, if any such technique should exist.

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like right-censored data, maybe survival analysis theory could help you? In the more classical setting, survival times (or more generally, the times until some event) are of interest. These are sometimes fully observed, but sometimes patients are lost to follow-up and then it is only known that their survival time is above the time until censoring.

Comment: @Sanderr Thank you, that sounds interesting/transferable .. I'll research that!

Comment: You could model the data even through linear regression but you have to take care of the censored observations. See Section 4.2 of https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdfview_1/euclid.ba/1393251773 for an example of classical regression with censored observations.